# Default options for "SpectralCentroid", AudioLocalMeasurements

Tags: sound

I'm trying to find the default options for the computation of the spectral centroid but cannot get any info in the window used, overlap if any, and smoothing applied to obtain the result.

Any way to get more info on how this is computed?